# How to write a program in python 3.3.4 that works out the area of a rectangle?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you write a program that works out the area of a rectangle, by collecting the height and width of the rectangle from the user input, calculates the area and displays the result? How would you do it with the volume for a cuboid as well? My code so far is: (I've just started python)

```
shape = input("> ")

height = input("Please enter the height: ")

width = input("please enter the width: ")

area = [height*width]

print ("The area is", 'area')
```

But I am receiving invalid syntax.

Comment: Hi! What is the exact error? Does it give any usable advice on the line of error, for instance?

Comment: What is your intend behind `shape`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3.x, `input` returns a string. So, both `height` and `width` are strings.

```
area = [height*width]
```

You are multiplying strings here and creating a list. You need to convert them to either integers (with [`int`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#int) function) or floating point numbers (with [`float`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#float) function), like this

```
height = float(input("Please enter the height: "))
width  = float(input("please enter the width: "))
...
area   = height*width
```

And then, its better to pass a single string to the `print` function, like this

```
print ("The area is {}".format(area))
```

Or you can simply print the items like this

```
print ("The area is", area)
```

Comment: Well `int` probably isn't the best type for a length =)

Comment: Why would it be better to use string formatting? I really can't see any advantage.

Comment: @Narcolei If the string to be printed, grows bigger `format` would be better, as it is a function call and all the data to be printed can be passed as parameters, and if you have to print the same data more than once, just change position numbers, etc etc

Comment: Sure, in some other, more complicated, situations using formatting is necessary. But I think it's a mistake to tell a beginner that formatting is unconditionally better even though,in this situation, it clearly adds complexity without any advantage.

Comment: @Narcolei I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("The area is", area)
```

and you don't need to store the area in a list - `area = height * width` is enough.

Just do it similarly to calculate the volume of a cuboid:

```
l = int(input("Please enter the length: "))
h = int(input("Please enter the height: "))
w = int(input("please enter the width: "))
vol = l*h*w

print ("The volume is", vol)
```

Notice that you need to convert the user input to an `int` before trying to do any math with them.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the user is only able to enter floats and not strings else you will get an error:

```
height = float(input("What is the height?")
```

once you have both of the inputs then to output:

```
area = height * width
print("The area is{0}".format(area))
```